# What's the Color code for Android Hint?

Tags: java, android, colors, hex

What's the Color code that Android:hint uses? 
By that I mean the grayish color.

Comment: What are you talk in about? What is your question?

Comment: i think he want to know the exact color as an rgb hex string.

Comment: @Kai Yes, The exact hex code that the hint is "made of".

Comment: The exact color hex that stock android uses

Comment: are you talking about this? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHintTextColors%28%29

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
R: 128 
G: 128 
B: 128
```

or

`#808080`

Comment: The color which @lapadets provide is better matching the hint on my nexus 7, Android 5.1

Comment: #9E9E9E seems to be better matching in my device. #808080 is too dark, whereas #A8A8A8 is a bit lighter than the default hint color. The best option would be to use @Pomanh 's solution if the colour should match accurately.

Answer (score 40):

in your xml use this:

```
    android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"
```

Comment: #808080 was too dark, this is perfect

Answer (score 7):

try #a8a8a8 :)

Create a **color.xml** file in the res/value folder

Then define it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="gray">#a8a8a8</color>
</resources>
```

Then use it like that:

```
android.graphics.Color.gray;
```

Comment: Don't call it grey. Give it a name that represents the application of the color. Call it "hintColor" or something.

Answer (score 4):

For getting hint color you can use getCurrentHintTextColor().
Then you need to transform int to hex format.
For example:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        int c = et.getCurrentHintTextColor();
        Log.d("Hint color", String.format("%X", c));
```

Answer (score 3):

in sources, holo theme :

```
<color name="hint_foreground_holo_light">#808080</color>
<color name="hint_foreground_holo_dark">#808080</color>
```

Material theme:

```
<color name="foreground_material_dark">@android:color/white</color>
<item format="float" name="hint_alpha_material_dark" type="dimen">0.50</item>

<color name="foreground_material_light">@android:color/black</color>      
<item format="float" name="hint_alpha_material_light" type="dimen">0.38</item>
```

so for light theme you can use `#61000000 //black 38%`

and for dark theme `#80ffffff //white 50%`

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to feed in color values with R,G,B Channels.
For gray,

```
    R=127 (hex = 7F), 
    G=127 (hex = 7F), 
    B=127 (hex = 7F),
    Hence, color-value = #7F7F7F -> go ahead and use this for gray color
```

OR, if you are lazy and dont want to do the above math - you can choose to use the inbuilt color options available. For example, in a simple TextView

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

There are more options, hitting **Ctrl + Space** after **color/** will show the other possible options.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter like this

```
class SpinnerAdapter(context: Context, items: List<String>) :
    ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item_layout, items) {

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val spinnerItemView = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent) as TextView
        spinnerItemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_gray_border_bottom_bg) // optional( here i am giving a style for spinner item)

        if (position == 0) {
            spinnerItemView.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    context,
                    R.color.hintColor
                )
            )
        } else {
            spinnerItemView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryText))
        }
        return spinnerItemView
    }

    override fun isEnabled(position: Int) = position != 0

}
```

And this is my `spinner_item_layout` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Spinner Text"
    android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In code:**

It is `android.R.color.tab_indicator_text`. You can get it by `getResources().getColor(android.R.color.tab_indicator_text, null)`. Or you can get it from RGB: `Color.rgb(128, 128, 128)`

**In xml:**

Add this attribute: `android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"` or `android:textColor="#FF808080"`